# Clipboard.js change button text on copy success with multiple buttons

Tags: jquery, clipboard.js

I'm a trying to change the text on [clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com/) buttons to say 'copied' upon success.

But the problem I have is that I have multiple buttons on the same page, and i'm struggling to target the clicked button. I'm getting an error **Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor**

I would love to know how to handle this better.

**jQuery**

```
$('.copy-link').on('click', function() {

  var copy_id = $(this).attr('id');

  var clipboard = new Clipboard( '#' + copy_id );

  clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
    $(this).text('Copied');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(this).text('Copy link')
    }, 2000);
  });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<button id="copy_1" data-clipboard-text="Test 1" class="copy-link">Copy link</button><br/>
<button id="copy_2" data-clipboard-text="Test 2" class="copy-link">Copy link</button><br/>
<button id="copy_3" data-clipboard-text="Test 3" class="copy-link">Copy link</button><br/>
<button id="copy_4" data-clipboard-text="Test 4" class="copy-link">Copy link</button><br/>
<button id="copy_5" data-clipboard-text="Test 5" class="copy-link">Copy link</button><br/>
```

**jsFiddle**

See my code above as a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/akh39dtc/

Any advice would be much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let cb = new ClipboardJS('.copy-link');
$('.copy-link').on('click', function() {
  //get a reference to the JQUERY object of the current button
  let theButton = $(this);
  var copy_id = $(this).attr('id');

  var clipboard = new ClipboardJS( '#' + copy_id );

  clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
    //use the .text method of the Jquery object
    theButton.text('Copied');
    setTimeout(function() {
    //same again
      theButton.text(e.text);
    }, 2000);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/2.0.0/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="copy_1" data-clipboard-text="Test 1" class="copy-link">Copy link</button><br/>
<button id="copy_2" data-clipboard-text="Test 2" class="copy-link">Copy link</button><br/>
<button id="copy_3" data-clipboard-text="Test 3" class="copy-link">Copy link</button><br/>
<button id="copy_4" data-clipboard-text="Test 4" class="copy-link">Copy link</button><br/>
<button id="copy_5" data-clipboard-text="Test 5" class="copy-link">Copy link</button><br/>
```

```
var clipboard = new Clipboard( '#' + copy_id );
```

Needs to be

```
var clipboard = new ClipboardJS( '#' + copy_id );
```

Edit: I'm a little confused I have the correct library, if you mean

https://clipboardjs.com/

My above code should work.

I am sorry I quite busy I will update the answer a final time with an explanation of how/why.

Comment: Cool thanks you, cheers for pointing out the typo and reformatting my code. Copying works nice. What am I doing wrong with the button text. I want the button to say 'copied' for 2 secs.

Comment: Would like to still see your final version too, thank you for your time mate. I'm using the latest Clipboard.js on my site so I will use Saurabh code but with `new ClipboardJS`

Comment: I've updated my answer now, hopefully this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Could you post the error it's giving try changing 'let cb' to 'var cb' perhaps?

Comment: Used you code to do this, works great now thank you https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/h49o0kg3/ and compiles

Comment: Since you are initializing the clipboard by ID, it doesn't look like you need to also initialize up front with the class. When I tested, `let cb = new ClipboardJS('.copy-link');` could be removed.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the scope i have use arrow function. ES6 arrow functions can’t be bound to a this keyword, so it will lexically go up a scope, and use the value of this in the scope in which it was defined. May this helps you

```
$('.copy-link').on('click', function() {

  var copy_id = $(this).attr('id');

  var clipboard = new Clipboard( '#' + copy_id );

  clipboard.on('success', (e)=> {        // use arrow function
    $(this).text('Copied');
    setTimeout(()=> { // use arrow function

      $(this).text('Copy link')
    }, 2000);
  });

});
```

Comment: That does actually work, interesting. https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/akh39dtc/2/, but why does my timeout not work tho. Thanks for you help

Comment: @joshmoto use arrow function in setTimeOut it will work, Currently in setTimeOut this refer to globel context. I have update it

Comment: It does not like to be compiled tho. Any ideas? https://imgur.com/6VrIcde

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $(".copy-link").click(function(){
            $(this).html("copied");
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button id="copy_1" data-clipboard-text="Test 1" class="copy-link">Copy link</button><br/>
<button id="copy_2" data-clipboard-text="Test 2" class="copy-link">Copy link</button><br/>
<button id="copy_3" data-clipboard-text="Test 3" class="copy-link">Copy link</button><br/>
<button id="copy_4" data-clipboard-text="Test 4" class="copy-link">Copy link</button><br/>
<button id="copy_5" data-clipboard-text="Test 5" class="copy-link">Copy link</button><br/>
```

Comment: This doesn't use Clipboard.js. Got it working now with the other answers.